# В Android Studio не могу собрать импортированный древний проект HitHub

Tags: java, android, android-studio, импорт

- Скачал и разархивировал проект с HitHub MultiPing-for-Android.
- При импорте в Android Studio получаю сообщение: **Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1**.
- Далее решал эту проблему, выполняя инструкции отсюда - [Как импортировать существующий проект из github в Android Studio](https://overcoder.net/q/282791/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-github-%D0%B2-android-studio). Второй ответ (13 голосов).
- В Gradle Scripts- > build.gradle(Module: app) добавил зависимости:

```js
dependencies {      
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
}
```

Ошибка в строке *compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])*  - **Не найдена документация.**

- Заменил **compile** на **implementation**. Результат - **IDE error occurred**

Помогите мне, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Начните отсюда, ваш импортируемый проект выглядит совсем древним.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: И ту инструкцию лучше забудьте, она устарела и возможно только мешает. Повторите без нее.

Comment: Я обновлял Android Studio двумя способами через **File >Settings...>System Settings >update** и использовал **JetBrains Toolbox**, но как и раньше  при импорте проекта  HitHub MultiPing-for-Android
получаю сообщение **Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1.** 
Обновленная версия Android Studio  **Dolphin 2022.3.1** , но при повторном открытии открывается 202**1**.3.1.  При попытке обновить выводится сообщение ПОСЛЕДНЯЯ ВЕРСИЯ УСТАНОВЛЕНА.

**Что нужно предпринять? Как импортировать проект?**

Comment: `jcenter()` замените на `mavenCentral()` и туда-же добавьте `google()`.

Comment: @woesss 
Заменил jcenter() на mavenCentral() и добавил google(). Результат - **Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.**  -> 'compile files('libs/admob-sdk-android.jar')'  **Как добавить метод компиляции для аргумента?**

Comment: Так замените `compile` на `implementation` во всех gradle-файлах. И другие устаревшие фичи на современные. Если не можете осилить самостоятельно - так хотя бы в вопрос их добавьте (только текстом, а не скринами)

Comment: @woesss  Безмерно благодарен! Я увидел проект на смартфоне!